# c# how to give relative path in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

here is the Folder structure

```
D:
|_ MYPROJECT
|   |_web.config
|_ SAMPLE
    |_xml-file
```

In web.config i have given the Absolute path as:

```
   <add key="XMLPATH" value=" D:\SAMPLE\xml file" />
```

Now, how can i change this path to relative path?
    I tried below , but it is not working.

```
    <add key="XMLPATH" value=" ..\..SAMPLE\xml-file" />
```

Comment: It seems your question is incomplete...the absolute path you're using is not there. =)

Comment: "I tried below , but it is not working." What, exactly is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Why you need relative path on `web.config`, can use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)??

Comment: How is `XMLPATH` used in the code? Perhaps it expects an absolute path?

Comment: An `appSettings` value is just a string.  The config file doesn't treat absolute paths or relative paths differently.  They're both just strings.  How are you *using* the path?  What is the actual error?

Comment: It should just be `..\SAMPLE\xml-file` (assuming you are starting from the directory where your web.config exists)

Comment: I tried using ..\SAMPLE\xml-file , but it is not working..

Answer (score 2):

I have this old old code.  Whenever I wanted to put a relative file-path-name in the settings-xml-config, I would call this helper function(s).

```
public class DirectoryHelpers
{
    public static string FindPhysicalRootDirectory(Page p)
    {
        string rootDir;
        //rootDir = p.Server.MapPath("/");

        rootDir = p.Server.MapPath("~/");
        return rootDir;
    }

    public static string FindVirtualRootDirectory(Page p)
    {
        return "~/";
    }

}
```

And an example:

```
public partial class DirectoryCheck : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = string.Concat("Physical Directory: ", Common.DirectoryHelpers.FindPhysicalRootDirectory(this.Page));



    }
}
```

APPEND1:

Once you have the FindPhysicalRootDirectory, you would read your RELATIVE file path from the web.config and use System.IO.Path.Combine to combine the 2 values.

Comment: Yea we can keep in application,But according to our requirements I must put the path in WEB.config only!

Comment: This would allow you to put all RELATIVE paths in your web.config only.  Your other option is to put the FULL path (no ".."'s) in the web.config.

Comment: I appended my answer to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
<add key="XMLPATH" value="SAMPLE\xml-file" />
```

Comment: web.config is at root of the project/webapplication, any folder at root can be accessed by just folder name:)

Comment: Read the question! The `SAMPLE` folder is not in the same folder as `web.config`

Comment: yea!! David, SAMPLE folder is out of the Project... How Can i accces that in WEB.config of my project!!!